# How can I make Webmachine and eredis work together?

Tags: erlang, redis, mochiweb, webmachine

I've been meditating on the question of Redis usage in my Webmachine application for a week. And I haven't enlightened yet.

I'm going to use Eredis and here is an example of usage:

```
{ok, Con} = eredis:start_link().

{ok, <<"OK">>} = eredis:q(Con, ["SET", "foo", "bar"]).
{ok, <<"bar">>} = eredis:q(Con, ["GET", "foo"]).
```

As I understand `eredis:start_link()` should be called somewhere only once. But then how can I get `Con` variable in my resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several solutions:

- register a redis connection locally or globally
- use a process register like [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc)
- keep the pid of the connection in the webmachine resource context
- use a connection pool like [pooler](https://github.com/seth/pooler) or [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy)
- in case you don't want to queue requests in a pool [dispcount](https://github.com/ferd/dispcount) could fit

---

Edit: misunderstood question, first answer below:

Webmachine and eredis are both Erlang [applications following the OTP principles](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html). If your application is OTP conform you can add eredis to the `applications` in your `.app` file, like the following:

```
{application, awesome_app, [
    {description, "My awesome app."},
    {vsn, "0.0.1"},
    {modules, []},
    {registered, []},
    {applications, [kernel, stdlib, 
                    eredis, 
                    webmachine]}
]}.
```

OTP conform applications use [releases](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html). After you create a release and start your application the applications in `applications` will be started before your app.

[Rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) is your friend for building and generating releases ([more info here](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades)). An alternative to rebar is [sinan](https://github.com/erlware/sinan) which is described in [this article](http://blog.erlware.org/2012/05/04/sinan-releases-and-being-right/).

Comment: Actually, your initial answer was what I had looked for. Thank you. It let me google the [eredis_pool](https://github.com/hiroeorz/eredis_pool) (Eredis + Poolboy) library.